# Angular guard loop and nodejs Cannot set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm Facing weird issue with Nodejs and Angular Guard , so let's explain the issue ,
at first this this is a log-in form with backend code

```
(req,res)=>{

  //defien properties and validation
  let email    = req.body.email,
      password = req.body.password;

  //call function form auth class
  auth.signinByEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(credential=>{
        return res.status(200);
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        return res.status(400).json(error);
      })

}
```

it's working good and return 200 as I did , but the issue when angular guard check if this issue is logging or not so this is a backend code for check user is logging

```
   router.get('/issigning', (req,res)=>{
      auth.getCurrentUser((user)=>{
        return res.status(200).json(user);
      })
    })
```

this function return true or null

and this is guard "IsUserGuard" code

```
return this.auth.isAuthorized().pipe(
  map( isAuthorized => {

    console.log(isAuthorized)

        if(!isAuthorized){
          this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
          return false;
        }

        return true;
  })
)
```

and this is my  routes configuration

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent,
        canActivate:[IsUserGuard,IsEmailVerifiedGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: InnerComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'profile',
                component: ProfileComponent,
                children:[
                    {path :'' ,         redirectTo:'details'},
                    {path :'details',   component:DetailsComponent},
                    {path :'avatar' ,   component:AvatarComponent},
                    {path :'username',  component:UsernameComponent},
                    {path :'email',     component:EmailComponent},
                    {path :'mobile',    component:MobileComponent},
                    {path :'social',    component:SocialComponent},
                    {path :'settings',  component:SettingsComponent}
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'inner',
                component: InnerComponent
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        canActivate: [IsGuestGuard],
        component : AuthComponent,
        children:[
            {path :'', redirectTo: 'login'},
            {path :'login', component: LoginComponent},
            {path :'register', component: RegisterComponent},
            {path :'foregot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent},
        ]

    },

    {
        path: '404',
        component: ErrorPageComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'error/:type',
        component: ErrorPageComponent
    },
];
```

so what happened when i click on "log-in button" it's login and he check if user has logged or not ! so this issue appeared in nodejs

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (d:\Nodejs Workarea\MyProjects\default-skeleton\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (d:\Nodejs Workarea\MyProjects\default-skeleton\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (d:\Nodejs Workarea\MyProjects\default-skeleton\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
>       at Object.auth.getCurrentUser [as next] (d:\Nodejs Workarea\MyProjects\default-skeleton\server\routes\auth.js:16:28)
>       at d:\Nodejs Workarea\MyProjects\default-skeleton\node_modules@firebase\util\dist\index.node.cjs.js:1349:22
>       at d:\Nodejs Workarea\MyProjects\default-skeleton\node_modules@firebase\util\dist\index.node.cjs.js:1453:21
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

and in angular it's freezing and I think the guard making loop requests

**Update**
this is function "getCurrentUser" code

```
/**
 * For get currently Sign-In User
 */
exports.getCurrentUser = (callback)=>{
    return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(callback);
}
```

and this is function "isAuthorized" code

```
    public isAuthorized(){
    return this.http.get(environment.api+'auth/issigning').pipe(map(data=>data))
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `auth.getCurrentUser()` from backend issue? This is backend issue, 99% certain of that. Just in case, you might add `auth.isAuthorized()` that the guard is calling - I'm interested in seeing how you set the auth stuff. (Btw, how? Cookies? Tokens, headers?

Comment: @Zlatko thanks for your interesting , I have add the functions's code